# кое поведение стоит ожидать от команды cmake "find_package" с опцией "REQUIRED"?

Tags: linux, cmake

Какое поведение должно быть у cmake файла если мы запрашиваем пакет  через команду "find_package" который заведомо не установлен с переданной опцией "REQURED" ? 
Судя по цитате с сайта

> The REQUIRED option stops processing with an error message if the package cannot be found.

выполнение команды `cmake ..` должно прерваться с ошибкой я верно понимаю ? Однако следующий cmake файл выполняется до конца не выбрасывая не единой ошибки.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

project(package_find)

find_package(MFC REQUIRED)
if(MFC_FOUND)
        message("MFC founded")
endif()
```

Подскажите где я не верно записал команду ? гуглил в сети, вроде везде команда запрашивания пакетов пишется схожим методом, так от чего поведение не соответствует ожидаемому ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно, `REQUIRED` в `find_package()` должен останавливать обработку и завершаться ошибкой, если модуль не найден; но ответственность за реализацию этого поведения лежит на авторе конкретного модуля. В большинстве случаев достаточно просто вызвать в модуле [`find_package_handle_standard_args ()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.html), но некоторые (в основном более старые) модули предпочитают обрабатывать это вручную, например `FindX11.cmake`.

К сожалению, не все авторы даже модулей идущих из коробки всегда заботятся о таких деталях. Судя по всему, так случилось и с `FindMFC.cmake`. То что `REQUIRED` игнорируется — почти наверняка является ошибкой в модуле и заслуживает отправки багрепорта разработчикам.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за подробный ответ.